# Can Visual Studio 2010 .Net projects be compiled with MonoDevelop in linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio-2010, monodevelop

MonoDevelop is a cross-platform IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. It claims that you can port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and Mac OSX.

I wanted to know if it is possible to compile large and complex .Net projects created in VS 2010 (Particularly C# projects) in MonoDevelop on Linux easily?

Will you face lots of compile errors when compiling .Net code created in VS 2010 or it can be compiled with minor changes?

Comment: Try it. It really depends on the solution, and if the .NET library parts you're using are available in mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are careful to not assume anything about things like file system layout and use libraries that are also portable, there would be little problems for porting VS .NET projects to MonoDevelop.

And one thing to keep in mind, Mono doesn't have the entire .NET Framework stack available. Almost all of the BCL is intact, but libraries like WPF are not available on Mono. Mono recommends you use GTK# for your GUIs.